# How to check the apt list of repository?

Tags: apt

I have a list of packages from my repository say `some_repo`,

Few packages in that has two versions and when I run my script to fetch the packages from repository the two versions of package is being downloaded,

I just want the installed version of the packages,

How do i get it?

Eg:

```
Package, Version         
xyz          1.2.3         
xyz          1.2.3.4
```

For Package `xyz` Version `1.2.3.4` is been installed, I just want the installed version of those packages which has two or more version

Comment: We need to see your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you mean by "running my fetch script" and "both versions are getting downloaded". But:

```
apt list --installed | grep packagename
```

Will list you your installed version of the package. Though if you want to use the output of apt you might need some sed to only see the package name.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you have aptitude installed, it will let you pick the version you want, and only install that one.

2) Via command line, add the version to the package name:
`sudo apt-get install package=version`

Comment: No my script is in such a way that it gets all the package name from the repository and, when i check that package which has two versions as mentioned in my question, apt-cache policy package-name gives me the installed version of it, but how do i get which version will be installed from repository when i have two versions for same Package??

Comment: apt-get will install the newest version unless otherwise specified by pinning or specifying the version. are you trying to get a script to do this?

Comment: ya it has installed the newest versions, but how do i know which version will be installed if it has two versions?? ya i am trying to write a script for it as well, i was just searching if i could get any command as such to do this

Comment: if it has two versions the default is to install the newest version (highest number). if you don't want the newest then specifying the version will get that version installed. I can't help with scripting. 'Pinning' gives priority, pinned versions or repo will have priority over others and be installed instead of a newer version

Comment: apt cache policy should tell you installed ver and candidate. candidate is the one that will be installed if you do apt-get install